# Belkin wireless 802.11g USB network adapter  not working

Tags: wireless, realtek

Hello everyone I really am new to this Ubuntu thing. I am now running the latest Ubuntu and windows on the same PC. Wireless connections work fine on windows but connects and disconnects on Ubuntu.

I am on ADSL with wireless router (Belkin and Belkin wireless network adaptor).

```
russell@ubuntu:~$ dmesg | grep rt 
[ 0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus: 
[ 0.000000] Movable zone start PFN for each node 
[ 0.000000] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x408 
[ 0.000000] Allocating PCI resources starting at 80000000 (gap: 80000000:50000000) 
[ 0.000000] Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware 
[ 0.000000] Enabling unmasked SIMD FPU exception support... done. 
[ 0.000000] virtual kernel memory layout: 
[ 0.004287] mce: CPU supports 4 MCE banks 
[ 0.035629] ftrace: converting mcount calls to 0f 1f 44 00 00 
[ 0.185268] ACPI: (supports S0 S1 S4 S5)
[ 0.193969] pci 0000:00:1c.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold 
[ 0.194048] pci 0000:00:1d.0: reg 20 io port: [0xbc00-0xbc1f] 
[ 0.194117] pci 0000:00:1d.1: reg 20 io port: [0xb000-0xb01f] 
[ 0.194189] pci 0000:00:1d.2: reg 20 io port: [0xb400-0xb41f] 
[ 0.194257] pci 0000:00:1d.3: reg 20 io port: [0xb800-0xb81f] 
[ 0.194485] pci 0000:00:1e.2: reg 10 io port: [0xc000-0xc0ff] 
[ 0.194495] pci 0000:00:1e.2: reg 14 io port: [0xc400-0xc43f] 
[ 0.194554] pci 0000:00:1e.2: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[ 0.193969] pci 0000:00:1c.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold 
[ 0.194048] pci 0000:00:1d.0: reg 20 io port: [0xbc00-0xbc1f] 
[ 0.194117] pci 0000:00:1d.1: reg 20 io port: [0xb000-0xb01f] 
[ 0.194189] pci 0000:00:1d.2: reg 20 io port: [0xb400-0xb41f] 
[ 0.194257] pci 0000:00:1d.3: reg 20 io port: [0xb800-0xb81f] 
[ 0.194485] pci 0000:00:1e.2: reg 10 io port: [0xc000-0xc0ff] 
[ 0.194495] pci 0000:00:1e.2: reg 14 io port: [0xc400-0xc43f] 
[ 0.194554] pci 0000:00:1e.2: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[ 0.194714] pci 0000:00:1f.1: reg 10 io port: [0x00-0x07] 
[ 0.194724] pci 0000:00:1f.1: reg 14 io port: [0x00-0x03] 
[ 0.194735] pci 0000:00:1f.1: reg 18 io port: [0x00-0x07] 
[ 0.194746] pci 0000:00:1f.1: reg 1c io port: [0x00-0x03] 
[ 0.194759] pci 0000:00:1f.1: reg 20 io port: [0xf000-0xf00f] 
[ 0.194819] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 10 io port: [0xd000-0xd007] 
[ 0.194829] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 14 io port: [0xd400-0xd403]
[ 0.194714] pci 0000:00:1f.1: reg 10 io port: [0x00-0x07] 
[ 0.194724] pci 0000:00:1f.1: reg 14 io port: [0x00-0x03] 
[ 0.194735] pci 0000:00:1f.1: reg 18 io port: [0x00-0x07] 
[ 0.194746] pci 0000:00:1f.1: reg 1c io port: [0x00-0x03] 
[ 0.194759] pci 0000:00:1f.1: reg 20 io port: [0xf000-0xf00f] 
[ 0.194819] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 10 io port: [0xd000-0xd007] 
[ 0.194829] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 14 io port: [0xd400-0xd403]
[ 0.194839] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 18 io port: [0xd800-0xd807] 
[ 0.194848] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 1c io port: [0xdc00-0xdc03] 
[ 0.194858] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 20 io port: [0xe000-0xe00f] 
[ 0.194892] pci 0000:00:1f.2: PME# supported from D3hot 
[ 0.194957] pci 0000:00:1f.3: reg 20 io port: [0x500-0x51f] 
[ 0.195097] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 24 io port: [0x9000-0x907f] 
[ 0.195212] pci 0000:00:1c.0: bridge io port: [0x9000-0x9fff] 
[ 0.195287] pci 0000:02:05.0: reg 10 io port: [0xa000-0xa0ff] 
[ 0.195360] pci 0000:02:05.0: supports D1 D2
[ 0.194839] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 18 io port: [0xd800-0xd807] 
[ 0.194848] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 1c io port: [0xdc00-0xdc03] 
[ 0.194858] pci 0000:00:1f.2: reg 20 io port: [0xe000-0xe00f] 
[ 0.194892] pci 0000:00:1f.2: PME# supported from D3hot 
[ 0.194957] pci 0000:00:1f.3: reg 20 io port: [0x500-0x51f] 
[ 0.195097] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 24 io port: [0x9000-0x907f] 
[ 0.195212] pci 0000:00:1c.0: bridge io port: [0x9000-0x9fff] 
[ 0.195287] pci 0000:02:05.0: reg 10 io port: [0xa000-0xa0ff] 
[ 0.195360] pci 0000:02:05.0: supports D1 D2
[ 0.195367] pci 0000:02:05.0: PME# supported from D1 D2 D3hot D3cold 
[ 0.195437] pci 0000:00:1e.0: bridge io port: [0xa000-0xafff] 
[ 0.224801] system 00:01: ioport range 0x4d0-0x4d1 has been reserved 
[ 0.224807] system 00:01: ioport range 0x290-0x29f has been reserved 
[ 0.224813] system 00:01: ioport range 0x800-0x87f has been reserved 
[ 0.224819] system 00:01: ioport range 0x880-0x88f has been reserved 
[ 0.224836] system 00:0b: ioport range 0x400-0x4bf could not be reserved 
[ 0.279897] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: irq 24 for MSI/MSI-X – Raven Aug 27 at 0:42 edit 
[ 0.195367] pci 0000:02:05.0: PME# supported from D1 D2 D3hot D3cold 
[ 0.195437] pci 0000:00:1e.0: bridge io port: [0xa000-0xafff] 
[ 0.224801] system 00:01: ioport range 0x4d0-0x4d1 has been reserved 
[ 0.224807] system 00:01: ioport range 0x290-0x29f has been reserved 
[ 0.224813] system 00:01: ioport range 0x800-0x87f has been reserved 
[ 0.224819] system 00:01: ioport range 0x880-0x88f has been reserved 
[ 0.224836] system 00:0b: ioport range 0x400-0x4bf could not be reserved 
[ 0.279897] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: irq 24 for MSI/MSI-X
[ 0.279910] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: setting latency timer to 64 
[ 0.287215] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing enabled 
[ 0.291459] input: Macintosh mouse button emulation as /devices/virtual/input/input2 
[ 0.299338] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: cache line size of 128 is not supported 
[ 0.346769] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00 
[ 0.347042] hub 1-0:1.0: 8 ports detected [ 0.347617] hub 2-0:1.0: 2 ports detected 
[ 0.348036] hub 3-0:1.0: 2 ports detected [ 0.348459] hub 4-0:1.0: 2 ports detected 
[ 0.348891] hub 5-0:1.0: 2 ports detecte – Raven Aug 27 at 0:43 edit 
[ 0.279910] pcieport 0000:00:1c.0: setting latency timer to 64 
[ 0.287215] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing enabled 
[ 0.291459] input: Macintosh mouse button emulation as /devices/virtual/input/input2 
[ 0.299338] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: cache line size of 128 is not supported 
[ 0.346769] ehci_hcd 0000:00:1d.7: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00 
[ 0.347042] hub 1-0:1.0: 8 ports detected 
[ 0.347617] hub 2-0:1.0: 2 ports detected 
[ 0.348036] hub 3-0:1.0: 2 ports detected 
[ 0.348459] hub 4-0:1.0: 2 ports detected 
[ 0.348891] hub 5-0:1.0: 2 ports detected   
[ 0.349073] PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp 
[ 0.349998] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1 
[ 0.350404] rtc_cmos 00:03: RTC can wake from S4 [ 0.350475] rtc_cmos 00:03: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0 
[ 0.350506] rtc0: alarms up to one month, 242 bytes nvram, hpet irqs – Raven Aug 27 at 0:43 edit 
[ 0.349073] PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp 
[ 0.349998] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1 [ 0.350404] rtc_cmos 00:03: RTC can wake from S4 
[ 0.350475] rtc_cmos 00:03: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0 
[ 0.350506] rtc0: alarms up to one month, 242 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
[ 0.355364] Using IPI No-Shortcut mode 
[ 0.356078] rtc_cmos 00:03: setting system clock to 2010-08-27 10:13:42 UTC (1282904022) [ 0.763804] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA 
[ 0.763811] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA 
[ 0.826587] udev: starting version 151 
[ 0.860561] hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected 
[ 1.116873] USB Mass Storage support registered. 
[ 2.734937] hub 3-2:1.0: 4 ports detected 
[ 13.477205] udev: starting version 151 – Raven Aug 27 at 0:43 edit 
[ 0.355364] Using IPI No-Shortcut mode
[ 0.356078] rtc_cmos 00:03: setting system clock to 2010-08-27 10:13:42 UTC (1282904022)
[ 0.763804] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 0.763811] sd 2:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 0.826587] udev: starting version 151
[ 0.860561] hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 1.116873] USB Mass Storage support registered.
[ 2.734937] hub 3-2:1.0: 4 ports detected
[ 13.477205] udev: starting version 151
[ 13.686799] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[ 13.953260] USB Serial support registered for generic
[ 13.958045] USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
[ 13.973144] option 3-2.4:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 13.973594] usb 3-2.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 13.973643] option 3-2.4:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 13.973747] usb 3-2.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[ 13.686799] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
[ 13.953260] USB Serial support registered for generic
[ 13.958045] USB Serial support registered for GSM modem (1-port)
[ 13.973144] option 3-2.4:1.0: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 13.973594] usb 3-2.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 13.973643] option 3-2.4:1.1: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 13.973747] usb 3-2.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[ 13.973783] option 3-2.4:1.2: GSM modem (1-port) converter detected
[ 13.973908] usb 3-2.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
[ 14.068472] parport_pc 00:09: reported by Plug and Play ACPI
[ 14.068526] parport0: PC-style at 0x378, irq 7 [PCSPP,TRISTATE]
[ 14.172348] lp0: using parport0 (interrupt-driven).
[ 16.456225] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
russell@ubuntu:~$
```

Answer (score 5):

We are going to need more info to be able to help you. Like what type of wireless adapter are you using and what Ubuntu version are you using.

------ **TRY 1: Failed**

One generic tip is to System->Administration->Hardware Drivers. Maybe you need to download some driver. If your wireless card is listed in the window that opens, please click the button to install it's drivers.

But with so little info this is just a blind shot.

------ **TRY 2: Failed**

Thank you for all the info. Belkin is famous for using different chipsets in the same product, F5D7050 uses at least 3 different chipsets. Anyway, the window's driver filenames are gold. Your card is likely a rt2500.

The most common problem with this card is that multiples modules (kinda of windows drivers) try to use it, conflicting. You will need to do some file-editing-foo to solve it.

Press ALT+F2 or open a console. Type or copy/paste:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Now at the end of the file append this two lines:

```
blacklist rt2500usb
blacklist rt2800usb
```

And reboot, if you are lucky it should be working after the reboot. If not, there are probably other kind of conflict, edit the file again, remove the lines, reboot, open a console and type:

```
dmesg | grep rt
```

Seems like no rt* modules is beign loaded. So it's my mistake. But if the wifi works (at times) it must be loading some drivers and windows drivers make it look like a rt2500...

**----------- TRY 3: Never Tested**

Another shot. There are some reports of disconnections with people using rt* chipsets with the current kernel. You can try to update your kernel.

You need to add [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~kernel-ppa/+archive/ppa) to your software sources. In the PPA page you can found detailed instructions about how to add them, but in short, you must open System->Administration->Sotware Sources, click on the "Other Software" tab, click add and write there *ppa:kernel-ppa/ppa*.

Afterwards you need to install the updated kernel. The easiest way is to open the Ubuntu Software Center, under get software select the new PPA and in the right panel choose to install the *Complete Generic Linux Kernel*, if you see two choose the one without pae in its name.

Reboot and let's hope that the linux gods will smile on us this time.

If you have any problem with the new kernel, you press ESC while booting for a menu that will let you boot from the old one.

**----------- RESOLUTION: OP just build another adapter**

Usually the easiest solution.

Comment: Thank you for the response. The Ubuntu version is 10.04 LTS
The wireless adaptor is a Belkin wireless 802.11g USB network adaptor. The same adaptor works fine on windows as you can see by my access here Sometimes it will connect then drop out other times nothing at all. I will swap over to Ubuntu now and try your generic tip.. Thank you

Comment: Tried the generic went to system-administration then hardware drivers the system went searching and came back with 2 drivers both for my Nvidia card the one recommended was active. There were no other drivers listed.

Comment: There too many Belkin usb adaptors. We need the exact model, more exactly the chipset that it uses. If you boot Ubuntu, insert the adaptor, open the terminal and type -sudo lsusb- without the -s. The computer will generate a list with the ids of all your usb devices. Please post back the wireless adapter one.

Comment: ok thank you...here we go...Firstly the box saysPart #F5D7050au version 2
Ubuntu when I run the command you suggest replies with Belkin Components F5D7050 Version 1000 WiFi

Comment: I looked on the installation disk that came with the USB wireless device and it has a folder for drivers  there are 4 files in this folder that I can see in windows rt25u98 system file and rt2500usb security catalog and rt2500usb setup information and finally rt2500usb system file...........I gather these wont work for Ubuntu?

Comment: THings are getting worse now I can't see my wireless at all on Ubuntu

Comment: They can work using ndiswrapper, but a native driver should be a better solution if it works.

Comment: Have you already tried the blacklisting?. If you did please remove the lines that you added and post the dmesg result.

Comment: Thanks for hanging in here for me, I am really new to Linux and I dont know what blacklisting is ...yet...so I guess I have not done it

Comment: Do I just type dmesg in the terminal?

Comment: ok tried the blacklist and the blacklist file was empty I typed in the two lines and rebooted...nothing ...so going back now to try dmesg now

Comment: I am not sure how to post the results here its quite a lot bigger than the posting box will allow?

Comment: Have you removed the blacklisting before posting dmesg?.

Comment: yes I had removed the blacklisting perhaps Ill just remove the Ubuntu

Comment: As you like. I suppose that it depends on why you have installed Ubuntu in the first place. You can also give us the id numbers that lsusb returned to you. That way we can try to narrow the problem.

Comment: I like the Ubuntu so far but I really need the internet I sure hope we can fix this problem

Comment: Strange, your card seems to use rt73, but it didn't appear on dmesg. Anyway, there is another complete different approach in the main answer under a TRY 2 heading.

Comment: well there has been developement of sorts: I came home from work and started the computer I must have left the disk in the drive it bboted up and asked if I wanted to try or install I thought just for a try I would run from the disk...well it booted up and found the internet straight away...so I did a complete reinstall
After the install it imediately found the network and told me I needed to upload and install the Video driver so I did that then it said I needed to update other things...I thought ok but the internet was lost by then and now its gone again and the stupid computer cant connect

Comment: And if it is a http address I have to put in then I will not be able to access it anyway because the internet will not connect...:(

Comment: You just need to click on the add button and write there ppa:kernel-ppa/ppa click accept. But yes, in the end it's an http connection. I was understanding that you had intermittent internet access. Maybe it's enough to let the system load the update.

Comment: There are lots of packages to install (kernel and modules), I don't really believe that a manual install (download one by one) is viable here.

Comment: Well I can see not much can be done without the internet connection I went out and bought another usb device...working well now on both Win and Linux
Thank you for you efforts

Comment: That's usually the best solution.

Comment: Hi Raven, don't try to use the comment system like a forum. You should be editing your original post with the information you've learned so other people don't have to filter through the comment junk. Thanks!