# Troubleshooting a wireless connection that drops out regularly

Tags: wireless

I have a NetGear wireless usb receiver in my desktop, that connects to my router (tried both DLink and Belkin) prefectly fine, however will simply disconnect after minutes, 10s of minutes, a couple of hours (no real pattern) at which time I will need to unplug and reinsert my usb receiver and reauthenticate to the router.

It appears to be happening alot more frequently when the pc is left unused for a while, and goes to the screen saver.

This has been hapenning on 10.04 and 10.10 (gnome) (and possibly 9.10 as well, though I have updated my gear since then)

*Rather than expect* someone to give me a magic bullet solution (that I'm happy to get :) ), as a novice user, what should I be looking at to troubleshoot this?

I have looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3085/wireless-not-working) question already, and to my (limited) understanding, don't see that it addresses the issue, unless there is someway of ascertaining what chipset it used.

**EDIT**

Looks like there are 2 drivers for the WN111 V2, the first does not support N routers, and the second is 'N speeds not verified'. I may have to shop around for a better one :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you consulted [Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported)?

Comment: Just the sort of thing I was looking for, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I use [IwScanner](http://kuthulu.com/iwscanner/) to figure out channel usage in my neighbors, and my access point power in different location in my apartement.

Anyway usual check could be :

- Bad wireless phone can disrupt wireless connection.
- Reinforced concrete wall / wiring configuration could block the signal.

Other than that you seem to point to a driver bug, then we could get more informations with the chipset of your usb adapter, and then dig deeper into the issue.

Comment: Nice tool, thanks, it shows a very consistent signal.